# Treating data with pandas, how can I get items from a column to a new one?

Tags: python, pandas

First, this is my problem:

I have a file in .xlsx format, like this bellow, but whit a thousands of rows:

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 15 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 20 |
| NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN |
| A | 5 |
| B | 55 |
| C | 40 |
| NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN |
| A | 19 |
| B | 35 |
| C | 12 |
| D | 78 |
| E | 25 |
| NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN |
| A | 119 |
| B | 235 |
| C | 112 |

As you can see, the "Variable" column is divided into groups, which sometimes have the same items ("A", "B", "C"), but other times have two more items ("D" and "E") .

I want a new .xlsx file that look like this:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 5 | 20 | - | - |
| 5 | 55 | 40 | - | - |
| 19 | 35 | 12 | 78 | 25 |
| 119 | 235 | 112 | - | - |

I've been trying to use .loc from pandas, but I have no success.

```py
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")

new_table = pd.DataFrame()
new_table ["A"] = table.loc[table["Variable"] == "A", "Value"]
new_table ["B"] = table.loc[table["Variable"] == "B", "Value"]
new_table ["C"] = table.loc[table["Variable"] == "C", "Value"]
new_table ["D"] = table.loc[table["Variable"] == "D", "Value"]
new_table ["E"] = table.loc[table["Variable"] == "E", "Value"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, can use:

```
(df
.dropna()
  .assign(index=df['Variable'].eq('A').cumsum())
  .pivot('index', 'Variable', 'Value')
)
```

Output:

```
Variable      A      B      C     D     E
index                                    
1          15.0    5.0   20.0   NaN   NaN
2           5.0   55.0   40.0   NaN   NaN
3          19.0   35.0   12.0  78.0  25.0
4         119.0  235.0  112.0   NaN   NaN
```